# Force a raw_input

Tags: python

How would I implement the following:

```
title_selection = raw_input("Please type in the number of your title and press Enter.\n%s" % (raw_input_string))
if not title:
    # repeat raw_input
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is often done with a "loop-and-a-half" construct with a `break` in the middle:

```
while True:
    title_selection = raw_input("Please type in the number of your title and press Enter.\n%s" % (raw_input_string))
    if title_selection:
        break
    print "Sorry, you have to enter something."
```

This method gives you an easy opportunity to print a message telling the user what the program expects.

Answer (score 12):

```
title_selection = ''
while not title_selection:
  title_selection = raw_input("Please type in the number of your title and press Enter.\n%s" % (raw_input_string))
```

It is necessary to define `title_selection` as `''` before hand, which means empty (also False).
The `not` will make `False` to True (negation).